# Why having a separate module for types?

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, types

Why is it common to put classes and types definitions inside special *Types* module instead of placing them within corresponding namespace?

For example, let's take [*Config*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yi-0.11.2/docs/Yi-Types.html#t:Config) record from Yi source code. Why has it been decided to define it inside [*Yi.Types*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yi-0.11.2/docs/Yi-Types.html) instead of [*Yi.Config*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yi-0.11.2/docs/Yi-Config.html)?

Comment: I would say that often these types can be mutually dependent or need a lot of imports.  It can be really easy to simply define a bunch of types in a `.Types` module, then re-export them where it makes more sense.

Comment: I don't think this is "primarily opinion based" because it's the result of technical limitations of GHC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's almost always done to avoid circular dependencies between modules. GHC handles them very poorly. They're theoretically allowed, but the mechanism is so painful they're nearly always avoided.

Comment: Could you elaborate? perhaps an example?

Comment: Look up "interface file (.hi files)" and "separate compilation"